# React Native Android to iOS migration

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have an Android app built from scratch using React Native. Can I migrate the same app to iOS? If so, how tough will it be?

The Android app is already built and working fine.

Comment: There might be a lot to work, if you were using any third party libraries in your code. You may need to make changes in Native side similar to android.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is done in React Native, you could build it using Xcode, of course you need a Mac, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started#xcode.

You can also try from command line

```
react-native run-ios
```

Remember that you still need to install Xcode and the tools needed to build on the simulator or your device.

Also remember that you might have to do some changes in your code, not always the code for android works in iOS, moreover if you are using native modules done by you or from a library.

Answer (score 0):

A project written in react-native should, by default, work on iOS.

Normally tho, every package you have used, some styles still differs from each other from platform, some things are avaiable to do on Android and not on iOS, some things are avaiable on iOS and not on Android.

Some packages needs linking. Some needs additional steps to run on iOS changing some datas/informations using xcode. (like deep linking).

On react-native 0.60 you need to install the pods manually as it's not done by the autolinking, there are a lot things to check and it may not be automatic for the majority of the cases